# Sortable, paged table retrieved using EntityFieldQuery

Tags: theming

How do you create a tabular, sortable and paged display in a custom module using `EntityFieldQuery`?  I've been looking all over for a working example and can't find one.  The entity has custom CCK fields, and using db_select it looks like I have to write joins and I'd rather avoid doing that if `EntityFieldQuery` brings in all the fields.

Answer (score 3):

To add conditions for the content of the fields, you use [EntityFieldQuery::fieldCondition()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3afieldCondition/7), while for enabling the pager you call [EntityFieldQuery::pager()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3apager/7) passing the number of rows shown in each page.
[EntityFieldQuery::fieldOrderBy()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3afieldOrderBy/7) could be handy, if you need to order the results by the value of a field.

Comment: A full example would be great.

Comment: Don't forget EntityFieldQuery::tableSort(). Helpful bit of history: http://drupal.org/node/885014

Answer (score 0):

Working example :

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
->propertyCondition('type', 'contenttype', '=')
->propertyCondition("status", 1)
->fieldCondition('field_custom', 'value', $value, '=');
$query->pager(10);
$queryResults = $query->execute();
$results = node_load_multiple(array_keys($queryResults['node']));
```

Results are nodes, You could format it like usual with form's "tableselect" element.