# EntityFieldQuery display pager

Tags: 7, paging, database

How do I display pager using EntityFieldQuery for fetch results?
I can't find complete example.

I am doing simmilar to:
[Sortable, paged table retrieved using EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6289/sortable-paged-table-retrieved-using-entityfieldquery)

But I miss part to output simple pagination links (1,2,3... for every next page).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect the only thing you're missing is adding the return from `theme('pager')` to the content you're building.

This is a small example that shows teasers for all nodes in the system, with 10 per page. You would use this in a page callback function:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->pager(10);

$results = $query->execute();

$content = node_view_multiple(node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node'])));

$build = array(
  'content' => $content,
  'pager' => array(
    '#theme' => 'pager',
    '#weight' => 10
  )
);

return $build;
```

More specific based on your comments:

```
if ($type == 21) { 
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery(); 

  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'product') 
    ->fieldCondition('field_razred', 'tid', array (607,608,609,610), 'IN')
    ->pager(10) // this is the bit you're missing
    ->execute(); 

  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($entities['node'])); 
  print render(node_view_multiple($nodes, 'teaser')) . theme('pager');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a good clue. I am not using it in context you suggest, though. I have my query like this:
if ($type==21) {
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->propertyCondition('type', 'product')
        ->fieldCondition('field_razred', 'tid', array (607,608,609,610), 'IN')
        ->execute();
}
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($entities['node']));
    print render(node_view_multiple($nodes, 'teaser'));

How would the method you mention apply in my situation ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just change the last line to `print render(node_view_multiple($nodes, 'teaser')) . theme('pager');` :)

Comment: changed, but to no effect. :) Please bear with me, im not experienced with theme() ;) Do i need to have something else ? Pager is not shown.

Comment: Sorry I didn't look further up...you need to call the `pager()` method on the `EntityFieldQuery`, I've updated the answer with an example, it should work...unless you've got other pagers on the same page in which case you might need to make a couple of changes

Comment: Yep i did it already (added ->pager(10)) but there is no pager, nor any error. Does theme('pager') depends on something i am not aware of ?  I built my theme on Framework theme. This code is in fact run in page.tpl.php (when conditions are met)

Comment: in addition: i am getting exactly 10 teasers, as suggested by pager (10) but there is no output pagination for next 10 entries...1,2,3 with links etc...

Answer (score 4):

Also been having some trouble with this - debugging statements [initializePager](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3ainitializePager/7) showed that the [optional $element parameter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3apager/7) was being set to 1 rather than 0.

If there is only one pager being displayed, try setting it explicitly to 0.

`$query->pager(10, 0);`

Comment: Never had luck with this. I ended up in writing my own pager functions/markup! Will check if this helps. Thanks