# How to display a pager

Tags: paging, database

I have example of fetching multiple nodes with EntityFieldQuery, but i am not able to show pager. (intial question here: [EntityFieldQuery display pager](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40843/entityfieldquery-display-pager))

```
if ($type == 21) { 
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery(); 

  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'product') 
    ->fieldCondition('field_razred', 'tid', array (607,608,609,610), 'IN')
    ->pager(10) // this is the bit you're missing
    ->execute(); 

  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($entities['node'])); 
  print render(node_view_multiple($nodes, 'teaser')) . theme('pager');
}
```

Does theme('pager') depends on something i am not aware of ? I built my theme on Framework theme. This code is in fact run in node.tpl.php (when conditions are met)

Comment: Execution of the EntityFieldQuery should initialize the data used by theme('pager'). As a side note, node.tpl.php is a template. Template contains presentation logic. Retrieving data from the database is not about presentation and therefor should not be included in a template, At least, use an hook_preprocess_node() implementation.

Comment: Thanks! Still, do you believe it should work even in tpl.files (pager?) Do you think using db requests in tpl files may slow down performance ?

Comment: It should work in a template. Doing DB queries in templates is not a performance issue, but rather a maintenance one. Queries should be done in helper functions, results should be formatted and injected into the template in preprocess functions. The templates itself should only contain simple loops, variable prints and other simple statements.