# How to offset an EntityFieldQuery when using pager?

Tags: paging, database

Is there some way to easily offset an EntityFieldQuery when using `pager()`, i.e. skip the first 3 nodes? `range(3, NULL)` doesn't work as the second value must be set, and `range()` also doesn't work when also using `pager()` which is a requirement.

Is there a substitute for something similar to this:

```
$query
  ->range(3, NULL) // <- Wishful thinking..
  ->pager(10)
;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Without further detail it's tough to tell what you're trying to do.  I would start by looking at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40843/entityfieldquery-display-pager and see if it answers your question.

Comment: @LesterPeabody Not really, but thanks. I have no issues with EFQ in general, it's just that I'm looking for a way to skip x number of nodes from the start (no matter the sort order), just like `range(3, 10)` skips the first 3, I would like a query with a pager that skips the first 3 (without max limit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question, you've asked if you can offset the results, without having to set the limit for the total results. Logically it would make sense to be able to set `$limit = FALSE`, to return all results. But I believe `range($offset, $limit)` requires you to enter both the offset and limit. A workaround is to enter `range(3,9999999999);`.

Second question, you've mentioned that the `-range()` is not working when `-pager()` is set. It's a known limitation. I would assume you can run a separate query to create a pager, but that would require additional SQL requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are of course correct. I mainly posted this in case I had overlooked something. Seems your workaround is the only solution though, although, in the end I believe I used multiple queries.

Comment: You're right. One query loads the items and another query counts the total items to initialize the pager.