# Help with Pagination

Tags: 7, database

I used this code to get a pager.

```
   if (isset($_GET['tid'])) {
     $id=($_GET['tid']);
     $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
     $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
     $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'escorts_product');
     $query->pager(2,1);
     $query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
     $query->fieldCondition('field_product_sub_cat', 'tid', $id,'=');
     $result = $query->execute();
    //print "<pre>";print_r($result);
    }
```

When I used `print "<pre>";print_r($result)`, it gave me 2 results on y page, whereas I added more than 2; this is right.

How should I get links for next page and also previous, next? Is there any other way to get a pager?

Answer (score 0):

To get the links for the next/previous pages you need to use `theme('pager')`.

[On this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40843/entityfieldquery-display-pager#answer-40846) you can find an example of that implementation.

Comment: Thanku @gerzenstl, I am using node_load() function after getting the nids `( $nids =  array_keys($result['node']);)`?but the link you have mentioned is based on node_load_multiple(), so can you elaborate please how should I achieve this using node_load()? I

Comment: Cool! Yes it works independently if you use node_load() or node_load_multiple(). All the calculation for the pagination it's done mostly by the pager() method.