# How to use pager_default_initialize with entity field query?

Tags: paging

In order to apply pagination on nodes which get rendered into block, I am using pager_default_initialize method. Basically I have written a query, execute that query and after that write [pager_default_initialize](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/7)() function. **But it is not applying limit to content per page.** i.e. **"paging" is not working.**

```
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
          ->entityCondition('bundle', $content_type)
          ->propertyCondition('status',1);
  $results = $query->execute();
pager_default_initialize(count($results['node']), 2);
```

here, the count of nodes is 4 and I want to display only 2 nodes with pagination.

```
return theme('calender', array('calender' => $output)).theme('pager');
```

Here I'm using theme('pager') for pagination interface.

**Pagination UI is displayed, but I'm not able to put limit "2" to the no. of count of nodes. Any suggestion where I went wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your motive is to create a pager for those results, I suggest you to use `->pager()` on your EntityFieldQuery.

See this question [EntityFieldQuery display pager](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40843/entityfieldquery-display-pager)

```
if ($type == 21) { 
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery(); 

  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'product') 
    ->fieldCondition('field_razred', 'tid', array (607,608,609,610), 'IN')
    ->pager(10) // this is the bit you're missing
    ->execute(); 

  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($entities['node'])); 
  print render(node_view_multiple($nodes, 'teaser')) . theme('pager');
}
```

If you necessarily want to use pager_default_initialize(), see this post [Creating pager in Drupal (without db_select() and PagerDefault)](http://knackforge.com/blog/sabareesh/creating-pager-drupal-without-dbselect-and-pagerdefault)

```
$per_page = 10;
// Initialize the pager
$current_page = pager_default_initialize(count($rows), $per_page);
// Split your list into page sized chunks
$chunks = array_chunk($rows, $per_page, TRUE);
// Show the appropriate items from the list
$output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $chunks[$current_page]));
// Show the pager
$output .= theme('pager', array('quantity',count($rows)));
```

Hope these examples will help you.